# Laravel и vue на хостинге

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Написала код на vue внутри laravel. Столкнулась с проблемой: при запуске сервера `php artisan serve` и `npm run dev` всё работает, когда отключаю run dev, фронт перестаёт подтягиваться и появляется ошибка:

> Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: resources/css/app.css.

Строка кода, на которую жалуется laravel, находится в файле с расширением `blade.php` и выглядит так:

```
@vite(['resources/js/app.js', 'resources/css/app.css'])
```

Пробовала `npm run build`, всё равно не работает. Соответственно на хосте такая-же проблема, фронта нет. Код из файла `vite.config.js`:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/sass/app.scss',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
        },
    },
});
```

Comment: [Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: resources/css/app.css](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/unable-to-locate-file-in-vite-manifest-resourcescssappcss)

Comment: Так у вас и нет resources/css - вы назвали resources/sass - если уж хотите свои имена папок и файлов - то нужно их конкретно определить по input - output